# SQL Software development tools

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, backend, ssms-2012

How do I interact with the code behind my SQL server ? I am using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio but that is a GUI, I would like to hard code parts of my database, using SQL.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the code behind SQL Server.  The product is not open source so the only way to interact is through something like Management Studio or some other interface using T-SQL.  In SSMS, just open a new query window and away you go.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I really appreciate you help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ordinary SQL Server *is* used as backend only and SQL Server Management Studio is used for debugging and database maintenance.

Applications are developed in different system/languages (SQL Server most of the time is paired with Microsoft .NET and languages such as C# or VB.NET).

So develop your front-end and middle-tier in a .NET language and use SQL Server as a backend database.

Comment: Gee thanks for downvotes. This is the last time I am trying to help. Lesson learned.